# Batch file to auto login in PuTTY and and run a specific command

Tags: batch-file, putty

I am using this command to direct login in SSH.

```
"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe" -ssh msnoc@10.0.0.11 -pw mypassword -P pwd
```

But after login i want to run a command every time

```
sh isdn st | i Bs
```

Right now I am handling 20 server and its too time taking to login every server and putting the same command.

How do I create a batch file to automate auto login and running the above mentioned command?

Comment: I believe what you want to use is PLINK.

Comment: You can use putty as well if you use the `-m` switch to feed it a script file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below command :

```
C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe" -ssh msnoc@10.0.0.11 -pw mypassword -P pwd -M "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\script.txt
```

where `script.txt` contain your commands:

```
sh isdn st | i Bs
```